# Slice indices limited to 0x7FFFFFFF

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

I'm playing with slices in Python (2.7.4):

```
class Foo():
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Single value
        if isinstance(key, (int,long)):
            return key

        # Slice
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            print 'key.start = 0x{0:X}   key.stop = 0x{1:X}'.format(key.start, key.stop)
            length = key.stop - key.start
            return str(length)
```

Everything seems to work as expected:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>>
>>> f[42]
42
>>>
>>> f[20:30]
key.start = 0x14   key.stop = 0x1E
'10'
```

Except it seems that the slice indices are limited to 0x7FFFFFFF:

```
>>> f[0xFEDCBA98 : 0xFFFFFFFF]
key.start = 0x7FFFFFFF   key.stop = 0x7FFFFFFF
'0'
>>> f[0x80000000:0x90000000]
key.start = 0x7FFFFFFF   key.stop = 0x7FFFFFFF
'0'
```

Why are slice indices not subject to the same `long` integer promotion as regular `int` values?  Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Interesting. I got the right results with Python 3.3.2

Comment: @aIKid Thanks - I didn't have immediate access to Python 3. That makes sense though since Python 3 only has new-style classes... See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19697420/119527).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've realized that this appears to be a limitation of old-style classes. [New-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes) (ones that derive from `object`) behave as expected:

```
class Foo(object):
   #...
```

Results:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>>
>>> f[0x80000000:0x90000000]
key.start = 0x80000000   key.stop = 0x90000000
'268435456'
>>>
>>> f[0xFEDCBA98 : 0x1200000000]
key.start = 0xFEDCBA98   key.stop = 0x1200000000
'73033532776'
>>>
```

I haven't seen this documented anywhere.  It's especially confusing, since this limitation is not in the `slice` class itself:

```
>>> s = slice(0xFEDCBA98, 0x1200000000)
>>>
>>> s
slice(4275878552L, 77309411328L, None)
>>>
>>> hex(s.start)
'0xfedcba98L'
```

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of searching I found this

In python 3.3, the slice start and end are found like [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d0bb3460b91b/Objects/sliceobject.c#l134)

```
start = PyLong_FromSsize_t(istart);
...
end = PyLong_FromSsize_t(istop);
```

but in 2.7 they are found like [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/026ee0057e2d/Objects/sliceobject.c#l86)

```
start = PyInt_FromSsize_t(istart);
...
end = PyInt_FromSsize_t(istop);
```

In 2.7, `PyInt_FromSsize_t` ultimately uses the size of `long` where as in 3.3, `PyLong_FromSsize_t` uses the size of `PyObject`. That is why it works fine in 3.3 and not in 2.7.

Comment: Very interesting! I guess the remaining question is, why does it work in 2.7 with new-style objects (derived from `object`) but not old-style?  I'm assuming the difference results in a different type being used under the hood, and it's probably for the same reason. I may dig into that if I get a chance. Thanks for the great research!